# Why isn't my dishwasher cleaning dishes effectively?

Tags: water, dishwasher, filter

The model I have is Whirlpool ADG 7570.
It does not wash every object in the machine as good as it should. When I start the machine it seems to be taking in water as normal, and it make normal washing, but it does not do that for too long.

Repeat: After a few minutes it stops and make a very low sound. That takes some 10 minutes or so not doing anything. Then it seems to be washing with very low intensity. It does not seem to be doing much. This repeats a few times until it stops and drains the system.
Sometimes there is a bit of residue left over.

I've tried the basic clean inside the machine etc. I saw videos how to do that basic cleaning stuff.

[image]

Only option left I had was to open the machine. So I did, and the first thing I noticed was the part on the right side of the picture. That tank. It looks like some dark muddy water inside, but I am not sure. Also see some white powder (looks like dishwasher powder) at the left bottom inside of that white tank. Anybody knows if it looks right or bad, and what I should do, what my options are? Should I take it out and clean it or? Is there another filter underneath the machine or just the one inside the machine (which I have allready cleaned?)

I don't know what these different parts in washing machine are called. I also saw some videos that objects could get stuck inside the impeller? I dont want to put back all the screws etc until I have some form of solution or know whats going on.

By the way the machine seems to be draining water as it should.

Edit: One more picture of this tank
[image]

Edit: Unable to accept @isherwood's answer because after some more diagnosis there seems to be an electrical problem that makes the dispenser door not always open. And somehow water is not pumping if the door opens, the washingpowder seems being stuck inside the dispenser, not everything goes out of it. My own solution is to buy a new dishwasher. It seems to be the easiest option.

Comment: A parts diagram would be helpful.  Can you post a link for one?

Comment: I tried to find, but without luck. There's a site with parts for the model here: https://www.4whirlpool.no/adg-7570-854275661890/catalogue.pl?path=600169&model_ref=3543140 but no diagram unfortunately.

Comment: TBH a lot of your descriptions of the sounds, sound to me like the normal sounds of my dishwasher.   Some low pitched sounds that I think are draining, then some periods of either very quiet or silent operation.  The only evidence you really have of anything wrong is the dishes aren't clean.  I was hoping the parts diagram could explain what the tank of dark liquid is.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the salt system?  My dishwasher doesn't use salt so I don't really know.  Do you have high iron content in your water?  Are there brown stains inside the toilet tank?

Comment: I was also thinking salt was the issue. The light indicated too low salt content, so I bought two boxes of salt. After filling the first box, the light still was on. Waiting a few days I started filling the second, and the light turned off. Its been low on salt for probably 6 months. So I wonder if maybe that can be the reason. Not sure if I should try the machine a few times and see if the problem fades away. However I think I should check the propeller just to be sure. Not sure about the iron content. Dont have a way to measure that here afaik.

Comment: Let's also consider other operator error: If some dishes are clean and others are not, it could be that you are not loading the machine properly, not scraping the dishes enough, not using the correct cycle, etc.  **Read and follow the manual carefully**.  Don't pile dishes on top of each other, don't nest them closely in each other.  You should be able to see all surfaces of all dishes before you close the door.

Comment: @jay613 I understand. But its strange that it happened instantly after one wash, which I filled the machine same way as I've always done before. I've added one more picture, just to show the side of that tank. It looks like its filled with alot of dark stuff. What could that be? It looks like it hasnt drained the dirty water. Is that a water tank?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145828/discussion-between-natural-number-guy-and-jay613).

Comment: Partial cleaning (partly @jay613) can also be caused by something getting through/past the filters and into the spray arm, then blocking a hole.  A grain of rice can be enough, and even smaller fragments can accumulate.  They can be a pain to get out, which explains why the upper arm of my dishwasher is held together with cable ties.

Answer (score 5):

The drain impeller is pretty easy to access on most models. Look yours up on YouTube and get a look.

My model has a flimsy steel coil spring securing the drain chopper that rusts through in a year or two. It then clogs and doesn't circulate water well. The motor is fine, but the chopper stops spinning.

I also had to replace the circulation pump recently. That's the big, louder motor. If it's making groaning noises it may be done-for. This is what I believe to be your problem, but it's worth looking at the cheaper fixes first.

Comment: I can't find my model on YT. It's an older model. Ill see what I can do nevertheless. Hm. You might be right, the motor does make groaning noises for a long time. However strange that it seems to be not doing that the first 10-15 minutes, then suddenly takes a nap and groans the rest of it's period.